How to mask passwords/token in ECS task definition JSON file?
Example:
Need to mask token in the given URI:
"logConfiguration": {
 "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
"options": {
"Name": "Http",
"Host": "listener-eu.logz.io",
"URI": "/?token=feuvDifewoZdk&type=fargate",
"Port": "8071",
"tls": "on",
"tls.verify": "off",
"Format": "json_lines"
 }
 },
"secrets": [
 {
"name": "/strapi/logz_token",
"valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:09862423065486:parameter/strapi/logz_token"
 }
 ]

Need to mask the token=feuvDifewoZdk - with SSM or Secret Manager before execution of the task definition.
Tried with SSM & replacing variable name or ARN at token=
But didn't work it is unable to resolve the SSM variable.
Any suggestion would be helpful ?

SecureString type for parameter: name and value  and type encryp
"URI": "/?token=${name}&type=fargate",

This is not working it’s getting empty token value in the logs.

It's difficult to see because the posted code isn't formatted properly, but the parameter is in the logging section of the task definition. You can't use secrets there.

Is there any other way to mask this token ? Other than SSM or secret manager

i don know if you can use environment variables, possible a good alternative
